# Prime number function, print prime factors

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some programming exercises in R and want to be able to check whether a number is prime and if not, print out the factors. This sort of works except the IF statement stops at the first non-zero remainder. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
num<-12
x<-2
while(x < num){
  if(num%%x == 0){
    print(paste(x, "is a factor of", num))
    x <- x+1
    print(paste(num, "is not a prime number"))
} else {
    x <- num
    print(paste(num, "is a prime number"))
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Could you please paste an example when it doesnt behahave as expected?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme What op posted ends up saying 12 is a prime

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to print prime factors you need to divide the number you just checked by its divisor and then continue checking with the *same* divisor before increasing.  This is why it is giving 4 as a prime factor when it should be two 2's.
2. if the number is not divisible by `x` then you also need to increase `x` to check for the next number, this is why it immediately says 15 is a prime number.

A very quick and dirty implementation with lots of room for improvement:

```
num <- 12
current <- num
x <- 2

while (x <= num - 1){
  while (current %% x == 0) {
    current <- current / x
    print(paste(x, "is a prime factor of", num))
  }
  x <- x + 1
}
if (num == current) print(paste(num, "is a prime number"))
```

In addition:
R is really not a language in which something like this should be done.
As it cannot be vectorized R is a very poor option to do these things. 
Checking for primality can be computationally extremely intensive, even with optimizations unless you use probabilistic tests (which may also be slow in R).
I would look into C++ (and Rcpp) if you want to do low level stuff while staying within R.

Comment: Some good points here, but the most important part for OP is that they need some kind of bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

```
num <- 7 # number to be evaluated
factors <- integer(num - 2) # initialize factors

# loop from 2 to num-1
for (i in 2:(num-1)) {
  # check if i is a factor of num
  if ((num%%i)==0) {
    # add i to vector of factors
    factors[i-1] <- i 
  }
}

# remove factors==0
factors <- factors[factors!=0]

# check if vector factors is not empty
# length(factors) returns false only if factors is empty
if (length(factors)) {
  cat(paste(num, "is NOT a prime number. Factors:\n"))
  cat(factors)
} else {
  cat(paste(num, "is a prime number."))
}
```

+++
EDIT: Changed as suggested by Roland

Comment: Please do not grow `factors`. Initialize `factors <- integer(num - 2)`, assign `factors[i-1] <- i` and do `factors <- factors[factors != 0]` in the end. Growing an object is a very slow operation (in any programming language).

Comment: Thank you to everyone - I appreciate your responses. I have a stats background and have used R a lot for analysis, but am new to programming and am just trying to challenge myself with some exercises. Roland - I don't quite understand what you mean by 'growing an object'? - apart from I will try to avoid that in the future.

Comment: Growing an object means here that in each iteration of the for-loop, the size of the vector "factors" is increased by 1 (in first version of post). This is not very efficient as the vector has to be copied in each iteration to a new location in memory. If the memory space is pre-allocated in the beginning, the algorithm is faster, as the vector remains in the same place of memory.