# R - prime factorization

Tags: r

Can you please help me with this excercise? I do not know much about math algorithms and even less about R language. Thank you.

A program reads an integer from the user. If the value entered by the user is less than 2 then program should display an error. Otherwise program should display the prime numbers that can be multiplied together to compute n, with one factor appearing on each line. For example:

```
The prime factors of 72 are: 2, 2, 2, 3, 3
```

I have this code in C that calculates the prime numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, num, isPrime;

/* Input a number from user */
printf("Enter any number to print Prime factors: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

printf("All Prime Factors of %d are: \n", num);

/* Find all Prime factors */
for(i=2; i<=num; i++)
{
    /* Check 'i' for factor of num */
    if(num%i==0)
    {
        /* Check 'i' for Prime */
        isPrime = 1;
        for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        /* If 'i' is Prime number and factor of num */
        if(isPrime==1)
        {
            printf("%d, ", i);
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

But output is only this

```
All Prime Factors of 72 are: 2, 3
```

Instead of this:

```
2, 2, 2, 3, 3
```

I also do not have a clue how to translate this to R.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Sorry, but I find it rather unlikely that if you'd search for something like "[r] prime factor", you wouldn't find several questions concerning R looking for a way to calculate prime factors, plus proper answers to those questions. Have you tried this? The first result for instance that I get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401364/prime-number-function-print-prime-factors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Recursion

```
prime_factors <- function(x, i=2, factors = NULL){
      if(x<i) factors
      else if(! x %% i) prime_factors(x/i, i, c(factors, i))
      else  prime_factors(x, i+1, factors)
}


prime_factors(72)
[1] 2 2 2 3 3
```

Using While loop:

```
prime_factors_Loop <- function(x){
  factors = c()
  i = 2
  while(x >= i){
    if(! x %% i) {
      factors <- c(factors, i)
      x <- x/i
      i <- i - 1
      }
    i <- i + 1
  }
  factors
}

prime_factors_Loop(72)
[1] 2 2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 7):

## Using packages

First, install the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) package [numbers](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=numbers) on your computer.

```
install.packages("numbers")
```

Now, load the package in your R session and get the prime factors.

```
library(numbers)
primeFactors(600851475143)
```

Comment: `numbers` is limited to max size of doubles, i believe.  For really large integers, consider `gmp::factorize`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I wrote some time back, it may require some improvement though. Updated it according to your requirement.

```
get_prime_factors <- function() {
  num <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter number: " ))
  n <- num
  if (n > 2) {
    numvec <- numeric()
    while(n %% 2 == 0){
      numvec = c(numvec, 2)
      n = n/2
     }
  i = 3
  while(n != 1) {
    while(n %% i == 0) {
      numvec = c(numvec, i)
      n = n/i
    }
    i = i + 2
  }
sprintf("All Prime Factors of %d are:%s", num, paste0(sort(numvec), collapse = ","))
}
else {
  stop("Try a bigger number")
  }
}
```

Running with few sample examples :

```
get_prime_factors()
Enter number: 100
#[1] "All Prime Factors of 100 are : 2,2,5,5"

get_prime_factors()
Enter number: 72
#[1] "All Prime Factors of 72 are : 2,2,2,3,3"

get_prime_factors()
Enter number: -9
```

> Error in get_prime_factors() : Try a bigger number